# Solr does not retrieve results for partial string match in shards

Tags: solr

In Solr i have 3 cores :

1. **Unicore**
2. **Core_1**
3. **Core_2**

   **Unicore**is the common core which has all the fields in **Core_1 & Core_2**

Im getting results for the below query for the string ***"50000912"***

```
  http://localhost:8983/solr/UniCore/select?q=*text:"50000912"*&wt=json&indent=true&shards=http://localhost:8983/solr/Core_1,http://localhost:8983/solr/Core_2
```

output :

```
"response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"maxScore":10.04167,"docs":[
```

but if i pass "5000091" instead of "50000912" by removing "2" at the end of the string i get zero results

output :

```
"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]
```

with the same query used which should return more results technically,am i missing some thing or its a bug ? can any one please correct me..

just for the reference this is one my resulting data from Core_2

```
"response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"maxScore":10.04167,"docs":[
  {
    "Storageloc_For_EP":"2500",
    "Material_Number":"50000912-001",
    "Maximum_LotSize":"0",
    "Totrepl_Leadtime":"3",
    "Prodstor_Location":"2000",
    "Country_Of_Origin":"CN",
    "Planned_Deliv_Time":"1",
    "Planning_Time_Fence":"0",
    "Plant":"5515",
    "GR_Processing_Time":"1",
    "Minimum_LotSize":"7920",
    "Rounding_Value":"720",
    "Service_Level_Days":"0",
    "id":"2716447",
    "Fixed_LotSize":"0",
    "Procurement_Type":"F",
    "Automatic_PO":"X",
    "SchedMargin_Key":"005",
    "Service_Level_Qty":"0",
    "MRP_Type":"ZB",
    "Profit_Center":"B2019",
    "_version_":1531317575416283139,
    "[shard]":"http://localhost:8983/solr/Core_2",
    "score":10.04167},
  {
```

Comment: So what is your actual query? Are those `*` part of your query, or are you trying to bold the relevant part of the query?

Comment: they are not part of query but * doesn't affect the results i have tested it . I think the problem is with the special character which is in the result from the above reference with Material_Number="50000912-001" .if i pass search string as "50000912" or "50000912-001" then it gives the outputs else no output ,for search strings like "5000091" or "50000912-00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr won't do any substring matches unless you've used a NgramFilter (which will generate multiple tokens for each substring of your original token).

My guess is you've indexed the content to a standard defined text field, which means that it'll tokenize on `-`. That means that what's being stored in the index for that document for `Material_Number` is `50000912` and `001`. Solr will only give hits when both the query and index side tokens match.

You have a few options - you can either add a [EdgeNGramFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter) which will generate separate tokens for each combination of characters from the start of the string, or since this is a numeric value, you can use a string field (and not a tokenized field, unless it uses the KeywordTokenizer) and a wildcard at the end: `q=Material_Number:5000091*` will give you any document which have a *token* that starts with `5000091`.